# Знак из строки в знак

Tags: python

```
X = input("число")
```

X читается как строка,

```
X = float(input("число"))
```

X читается как число, но если я введу знак, то он читается как строка.
И как его превратить в из строки знак?

```
a = float(input("Введите число 1 "))
c = input("Введите знак ")
b = float(input("Введите 2 число "))

print(a, c, b)
```

Comment: Никак, нет такого типа "знак". Напишите, какую конкретно задачу вы пытаетесь решить.

Comment: Просто интересно стало, ведь число из строки в число перевести можно, а знак почему-то нет

Comment: Потому что в python нет такого типа "знак", знак (оператор) не может существовать отдельно, вне какого-то выражения, и нет никакого способа отдельный знак записать в переменную (кроме как в виде строки, ну или создать какой-то свой класс для хранения знаков).

Comment: А знак и есть строка, поэтому его уже некуда переводить.

Comment: Уточните, что за знак и какой точно у вас ввод

Comment: a=float(input("Введите число 1 "));c=input("Введите знак ");b=float(input("Введите 2 число "));print(a, c, b)

Comment: Добавьте код в сам вопрос (нажмите "править" под вопросом и отредактируйте его).

Comment: @Дмитрий вы так и не ответили, какую задачу пытаетесь решить... нужно выполнить действие над двумя введенными числами в зависимости от знака и вывести результат?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Все, что возвращает input() - это строка.
Можно проверить, чем является каждый элемент (или все) через [методы строки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

```py
for char in my_input:
    if char.isdigit():
        print(f'{char} - digit')
    elif char.isalpha():
        print(f'{char} - letter')
    else:
        print(f'{char} - sign')
```

при

```py
my_input = input()
>? a2K5?7*1
```

выведет:

```
a - letter
2 - digit
K - letter
5 - digit
? - sign
7 - digit
* - sign
1 - digit
```

или

```
>>> input().isdigit()
>? 123456
True
```